# Play on words: translation for "seasoned advice" related to food?

Tags: traducción, expresiones, solicitud-de-término, solicitud-de-modismo

There's this nice stack about cooking, called [Seasoned Advice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com).

We were discussing how good of a name that is for a Q&A site about food, because "seasoned" means "condimented", but also "experienced; of distinctive quality".

However, we weren't able to come up with a Spanish translation that managed to convey all the nuances of the name.

What could be a good Spanish translation of "**seasoned advice**" that conveys both the "advice about food" and the "experienced, quality advice" meanings?

Comment: Consejos con sazón, cocinando con sazón.  I would like the latter better as a title for that site, even though it doesn't convey the *advice*.

Comment: O *razón con sazón*.

Comment: @aparente001 *consejos con sazón* es buenísima, merece ser una respuesta

Comment: @blonfu y walen - Pero no sé cómo documentar mi idea, como Respuesta.

Comment: @aparente001 solo necesitas el diccionario, las definiciones 1 y 3 del [DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XNAUzjg) ya te dan los dos significados que busca walen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yo tengo un par de propuestas.

> **Consejos curtidos**

Por un lado *curtido* es un sinónimo de experimentado y por otro también se puede decir de un fruto encurtido. Tal vez el doble sentido no sea muy evidente ya que esa última definición no es muy común.

A partir de la propuesta de @CarlosAlejo *consejos con sustancia* he pensado en el jugo de los alimentos y me ha llevado a:

> **Consejos jugosos**

La tres primeras definiciones que nos da el [Diccionario de la lengua española](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MbCiY9J) sirven perfectamente al propósito que buscamos de un doble sentido entre algo relacionado con los alimentos (las dos primeras) y la calidad de los consejos (la tercera).

> **1.** adj. Que tiene jugo.
>   **2.** adj. Dicho de un alimento: **sustancioso** (‖ rico en valor nutritivo).
>   **3.** adj. Valioso, estimable.

Comment: Me gustan los _consejos jugosos_ no tanto los _curtidos_ :-)

Answer (score 7):

Una que se me ocurre es:

> **Consejos con miga**

Por supuesto, *miga* hace referencia a la miga del pan, una clara alusión gastronómica. Pero al mismo tiempo, y según el DLE, *[miga](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PDtkw27)* significa:

> 3. f. coloq. Sustancia y virtud interior de las cosas físicas.
> 4. f. coloq. Sustancia o importancia. *Discurso de miga. Hombre de miga.*

Es decir, estaríamos diciendo que estamos dando consejos con sustancia o con importancia. Lo cual, dicho sea de paso, es otra buena traducción:

> **Consejos con sustancia**

Dado que *[sustancia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YpIehqm)* hace referencia al jugo extraído de un alimento o a su valor nutritivo (acepciones 5 y 6), pero también significa "parte más importante de algo" (acepción 2) o "valor, importancia o utilidad de algo" (acepción 4). Así, un "consejo con sustancia" es un consejo de valor, de importancia o de utilidad.

También podría valer "consejos sustanciosos", pero me suena mejor "con sustancia".

Comment: Lo de _miga_ es difícil de entender a este lado del charco, pero _consejos con sustancias (sustanciosos)_ suena muy bien.

Answer (score 6):

Posiblemente no la mejor opción, pero [*sazonado*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XNBhVZw) tiene el significado de

> 1. adj. Dicho de una frase, de un dicho o de un estilo: **Sustancioso y expresivo**.

que va por cierto muy a la par con una de las magníficas propuestas de [Carlos Alejo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22270/5481), aunque admito que "consejo sazonado" no sería mi primera opción.

Creo que otros posibles juego de palabras mejores podrían ser

> **consejos al gusto**
>
> **consejos con mucho gusto**

haciendo un juego de palabras entre el sentido corporal que permite percibir los sabores (el gusto) y los distintos significados de "gusto", entre ellos la locución adverbial "al gusto" (preferencia de cada uno) y "con mucho gusto" (usada para indicar que alguien accede a algo que se le pide, en este caso, responder una pregunta del *Seasoned Advice stack*).

Comment: Me gusta *al gusto* valga la redundancia.

Comment: y a mi me gusta _con mucho gusto_ :-)

Answer (score 2):

Se me ha ocurrido otra posibilidad, pero que solo responde a medias. En este caso dejaría de lado la traducción de *seasoned* y haría un juego de palabras con **"reserva"**.

En la pregunta se explica que algunas de las acepciones de "seasoned" son *"experienced, quality (advice)"*

Los vinos se categorizan como de *crianza*, *reserva* y *gran reserva*. Si nos centramos en el aspecto de "quality" (y de la *edad* o *veteranía*, que es otra de las acepciones de *seasoned*) podría hacerse un juego de palabras con "reserva" como

> **Consejos Culinarios Gran Reserva**

con el doble sentido de "algo que es de gran categoría" y/o mejorado con el paso del tiempo, y las acepciones de "guarda o custodia que se hace de algo; recursos".

> [reserva](http://dle.rae.es/?id=W9AlOxX)
>
> 1. f. Guarda o custodia que se hace de algo, o prevención de ello para que sirva a su tiempo.
> 2. f. pl. recursos (‖ elementos disponibles).

Ya que se guardan estos "recursos" que con las preguntas y respuestas del stack. Se pierde la connotación de "experimentado" de *seasoned*, pero se gana en "calidad" y "veteranía".

Answer (score 1):

**Consejos con sazón**

Para *sazón*, me recomendaron las definiciones 1 y 3 del DLE pero no me gustan.

Linguée me da como traducciones al inglés para *sazón*: *seasoning* y *zing*.  Me parece much mejor.  Tiene sabor y tiene algo especial (*zing*).

También, y esto sí está en el DLE, para que algo salga bien sazonado, no hay que servir el plato muy poco tiempo después de poner las hojas de oler.  Se debe dar tiempo para que se combinen bien los sabores.  En ese sentido un consejo bien sazonado sería algo que se pensó bien (no se dijo a la lijera), y es un consejo que sale de la experiencia (no de teoría nomás).

Answer (score -3):

Creo que una buena buena propuesta sería:

> Consejos picantes

Estas serían las definiciones, todas aplican:

Sobre la palabra **picante**:

> **adj.** Que pica en el paladar: pimientos picantes. También m.:
>       le sienta mal el picante.
>
> Malicioso o atrevido en lo que respecta a temas sexuales:
>       chiste picante.

Comment: No veo el juego de palabras en este caso. Cierto que con "picante" puedes tener el doble significado de "tema sexual" y "que pica a la lengua o paladar", pero el _stack_ de la pregunta es sobre cocina y no tiene nada de temas sexuales. **Podrías explicar un poco más el juego de palabras que quieres hacer con picante, por favor?** Cómo aplican las acepción de "tema sexual" a SeasonedAdvice.SE? Yo no consigo verlo.

Comment: Concuerdo con @Diego; no veo qué sentido tiene lo de los temas sexuales.